# How can i modify my code to correctly print the pattern described?

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to print this pattern using only while loops. My code works when the height (h) is even but when the height (h) is odd it does not work. Let me know where I need to make changes. The function tapis_2(l,h) must use the other 3 functions and only while loop need to be used.

for example tapis_2(5,5) should print the pattern below:

```
*#*#*
*#*#*
*#*#*
*#*#*
*#*#*
```

But when I run my code I get the pattern below:

```
*#*#
*#*#
*#*#
*#*#
*#*#
```

---

```
def etoile():
    print('*',sep='',end='')
    
def diese() :
    print('#', sep='',end='')
    
def nouvelle_ligne() :
    print()

def tapis_2(l,h):
    
    i = 0
    
    
    while i<l:
        j = 0
        while j<h//2:
            etoile()
            diese()
            j += 1
        nouvelle_ligne()
        i += 1
```

Comment: Is that a correct pattern you're showing? And for people who don't necessarily want to run your code first, can you give examples of the inputs you use and their respective outputs from your code, and describe which ones are 'correct' and which ones are 'wrong'?

Comment: Edit the question to show a call to "tapis_2" with specific numbers (those for which it fails), the expected and the real output as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I don't see any problem with `tapis_2(7, 10)`. It prints 7 lines of `*#*#*#*#*#` as expected.

Comment: Your parameters seem to be backwards. `l` is the height, while `h` is the length of each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should look like:

```
def tapis_2(l,h):
    
    i = 0
    
    while i<l:
        j = 0
        while j<h//2:
            etoile()
            diese()
            j += 1
        # If h is odd, append a final asterisk to the line
        if h % 2 == 1:
            etoile()
        nouvelle_ligne()
        i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I had to add and if condition but couldn't figure out where to do so. Your answer is clear and very helpful. Thanks.